# Web Service List Record

Tags: c#, xml, web, service

Below is my result from web service, how can I change the record name so that it's uniquely identified? e.g. `Record1`, `Record2`, `Record3`.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfRecord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Record> /*How to change this Record to Record1*/
<item>
Buffalo DriveStation Combo 3.5 inch External Hard Drive USB 2.0 1.5TB Quadra
</item>
<qty>1</qty>
<qtyapproved>1</qtyapproved>
<availability>0</availability>
<description>Returned</description>
<itemdescription>-</itemdescription>
<id>188</id>
</Record>
<Record>
<item>eSataII HDD Docking with 1TB 3.5 inch hard disk</item>
<qty>1</qty>
<qtyapproved>1</qtyapproved>
<availability>0</availability>
<description>Returned</description>
<itemdescription/>
<id>184</id>
</Record>
</ArrayOfRecord>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the record name include a unique column in the resultset being returned by the web service, you can use a sequence number if you do not have any unique column.

For example you can add itemId a new column in Record

```
<Record> /*How to change this Record to Record1*/
<itemId>1</itemId>
<item>
Buffalo DriveStation Combo 3.5 inch External Hard Drive USB 2.0 1.5TB Quadra
</item>
<qty>1</qty>
<qtyapproved>1</qtyapproved>
<availability>0</availability>
<description>Returned</description>
<itemdescription>-</itemdescription>
<id>188</id>
</Record>
```